# Powershell select item in dropdown list using internetexplorer.application

Tags: powershell, web-scraping, internet-explorer

I am attempting to select a dropdown item via Powershell. Its using Javascript. So far I'm only achieved to login and get a bunch of methods by getting the Element. See below.

```
# Create an ie com object
$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application;
$ie.visible = $true;
$ie.navigate($url);
# Wait for the page to load
while ($ie.Busy -eq $true){ Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1000; }

# Login
Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "Attempting to login.";
# Add login details
try
{
    $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("user") = $username
    $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("pass") = $password
    $ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementsByName("submit")

    Do{Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100}While($ie.Busy -eq $True)    
}
catch
{
    $_.Exception.Message
}

#get dropdown elementarray
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('contentPlaceHolderId')
#get methods
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('contentPlaceHolderId') | gm
```

Does anybody know how to select a specific element in the placeholder? Methods are too many to fit in the post.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Have you searched for possible existing answers? 2) Is the url public and can you share it?  3) Without seeing the relevant html for the dropdown is it difficult to help troubleshoot. You can use [edit] and the toolbar to insert html (not as an image please) 4) As IE is no longer supported, and withdrawn from Windows 11, you will likely need to migrate code, so maybe a better time investment is to start writing for a supported browser rather than IE?

Comment: @QHarr I actually found the method after trial and error. 

($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('contentPlaceHolderId') | Where-Object { $_.innerHTML -eq 'DropDownItemToSelect' }).selected = $true

However. The download box is opening and am unable to automate where to download the file since the site is using javascript. 

Also looking at using Invoke-WebRequest but can't find much information on how to select dropdown items or manipulating javascript to download a specific location.

Answer (score 0):

For anybody else the answer is:

```
($ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('$contentPlaceHolderId') | Where-Object { $_.innerHTML -eq '$DropDownElementName' }).selected = $true
```

Clicking a button is:

```
$ie.Document.IHTMLDocument3_getElementById('$button').click();
```